# Multiline text (wordwrap) with drawAtPoint?

Tags: iphone, sdk, ios4, word-wrap, cgpoint

is there a way to draw multiline text with drawAtPoint?
I have tried UILineBreakModeWordWrap but doesnt seem to be working?

How would you convert this code to a working multiline text??

```
point = CGPointMake(boundsX, 50);
[self.heading drawAtPoint:point forWidth:labelWidth withFont:mainFont minFontSize:12.0 actualFontSize:NULL lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`drawAtPoint:` doesn't support multiline text. You can use `drawInRect:` method instead.

**Edit:** (Copying @George Asda's comment below to here)

```
[self.heading drawInRect:(contentRect) withFont:mainFont    
        lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Comment: Something like this? [self.heading drawInRect:(contentRect) withFont:mainFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];

Answer (score 1):

```
[_text drawWithRect:_textRect options:**NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin | NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine** attributes:attributes context:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

This cannot be done with the `NSString` drawAtPoint method. From the documentation:

> Draws the string in a **single line** at the specified point in the
>   current graphics context using the specified font and attributes.

Could you perhaps use a simple `UILabel`?

**EDIT**

You can calculate the height of a UILabel like this:

```
//Calculate the expected size based on the font and linebreak mode of your label
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(296,9999);

CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourString sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font 
                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode]; 

//adjust the label the the new height.
CGRect newFrame = yourLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = newFrame;
```

Comment: how could i do that? (UILabel)

Comment: Would this also be correct? [self.heading drawInRect:(contentRect) withFont:mainFont lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];